# How to get Address to geocode latitude and longitude value?

Tags: drupal, geolocation, latitude-longitude, geocode, geocoder

I want to get latitude and longitude of text address by code in drupal.

I tried below code but $providers and $addressCollection is getting empty.

```
  $address = '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Mountain View, CA 94043';
  $providers = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('geocoder_provider')->loadMultiple($provider_ids);
  $addressCollection = \Drupal::service('geocoder')->geocode($address, $providers);
```

Also same result its not working.

```
    $geocoderManager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.geolocation.geocoder');
    $geocoder = $geocoderManager->getGeocoder('nominatim');
    $geocode = $geocoder->geocode($address);
```